# DataStax cassandra core drive dependents on vulnerable Guava-19

Tags: security, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

[DataStax cassandra core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-mapping/3.7.1) java drive is having a transitive dependencies on guava-19 (including latest DataStax) which is having a security vulnerable ([CVE-2018-10237](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-10237)).

To fix this when I tried excluding [guava-19.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/19.0) dependencies from DataStax drive and replaced with [guava-27.1-jre](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/27.1-jre) I got following error on run-time and confirmed same by decompileing the latest guava driver; looks like from guava-20.0 they removed the *FutureFallback* class and there is no backward compatibility with latest cassandra drive.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback
```

Any help or quick fix or alternative is highly appreciable.

Comment: What do you mean by 0-day? Theoretically, Java driver shouldn't be affected by this CVE.

Comment: Got it, corrected! Thanks. But do we have any update available or timeline and how do you say "shouldn't be affected" ?

Comment: I’ve asked dev team to provide comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vulnerability relates to Guava classes `AtomicDoubleArray` and `CompoundOrdering`; we don't use them in the driver.

We've addressed Guava compatibility issues in [JAVA-1328](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1328). The driver is compatible with 16.0.1 to latest, there is an internal compatibility layer to address the breaking changes in 19. I've just tried a simple client that overrides the dependency to 27.1-jre, things work as expected.

How were you testing and what was the stack trace of your error?

Answer (score 1):

I exactly have the same issue & fix was to ignore Guava from 3 places, not only from drivers. Below is the sample for your fix. It worked for me & I am using Guava 27 now.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>${datastax.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>${datastax.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
    <version>${datastax.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Later u can use your own Guava like below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>${guava.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What is your cassandra-driver-core version?